# html5 embedded animations in pdf

Tags: html, animations, media9

For long time I have been using flash animations in pdf (lately using media9), but always relied on windows and acrobat to have embedded animations and auto-start (no click) in my presentations. Knowing that flash will be "killed" by HTML5 and to be independent at least of the of OS, I'm trying to get the same behaviour but now using the browser to display the animation.

My question is: Is there any package like media9 to be open by the browser with startup mechanism? I know that hyperref allows the html inclusion but requires the click and opens the browser.

Since I'm using powerdot I still rely on Latex+dvips+ps2pdf scheme

Pedro

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for now, after a year...

Comment: Even after 3 years there is no solution...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user not active anymore + likely no answer.